# Install new guest OS in virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere

I connect to a virtual machine using vsphere client. I have installed a guest os (windows 10), but now I want to change it to windows server 2016. The os was installed through a datastore iso file. The windows server iso file is also available there.

So, how can I do this? Is there a way to format the drive the windows are installed and start from the beginning? (I don't care to keep any previous files or programs installed). Some other way?

Keep in mind that I don't have complete authority over the vm, so I cannot delete it and recreate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you can mount the ISO to the VM itself, you should be fine.

Start by mounting the ISO to the VM, then restart the guest OS. There should be a prompt to boot from ISO, follow that and you will be able to install Server 2016 to the system.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question, in case someone else has the same problem.

The guest OS would load immediately, without allowing the user to go to the BIOS and select to boot from the ISO.

There is a setting you can adjust for waiting time before the windows are loaded. This was zero and had to add a few seconds, in order to be able to enter the BIOS.

I am not sure where this setting is, since I was not the one to change it (I didn't have the rights). Maybe someone else can add this.